# Azure AD B2C vs Auth0

Tags: authentication, sso, azure, saas

I am trying to work on security architecture for our SaaS application.
The good finding was Azure AD B2C which is launched recently. And first comparison was with Auth0.

Is this is correct comparison? What would be advantages of one over another?

We need

- SSO / OAuth 2 few standard components that both provides
- Don't want to manage identity or passwords at our server level!
- Standardized boilerplates of code so all internal App builders can follow and implement (both of them provides good SDKs)

Auth0 launched on-prem version as well. Can functions of Azure B2C be replaced by ADFS?

Answer (score 2):

Azure B2C is completely a PaaS service, no way/need to host this onpremise.
Both handle the users and the login screens.

Regarding B2C vs ADFS:
B2C is for all external customers.
ADFS is a wrapper around your corporate AD, so that is not so suitable for external customers.